# Enabling ARMv8 on Raspberry Pi 3 B

Tags: pi-3, arm, config.txt

According to [this article](https://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt#Enable_ARMv8_on_RPi3B) I should be able to switch to ARMv8 on my Raspberry Pi Model 3B, but I'm getting ["rainbow screen"](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Coloured_splash_screen) after adding to `config.txt` the line:

```
arm_control=0x200
```

- Why is it not working?
- Is it even worth switching from ARMv7 to ARMv8 (taking into account I'm willing to compile some C++ programs in the future).

*I'm using Raspbian 9.1 "stretch" and `/prc/cpuinfo` reports "ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)".*

Comment: Worth? Depends! If you want to roll your own kernel, then yes. Do you want to?

Comment: @Fabian, if its needed/worth than - yes. But isn't the Raspbian 9.1 "ARMv8 -ready"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3 and 64-bit kernel, differences between armv7 and armv8](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49466/raspberry-pi-3-and-64-bit-kernel-differences-between-armv7-and-armv8)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think others here have done a good job answering:

> Is it even worth switching from ARMv7 to ARMv8

Various software cited to require ARMv8 includes CockroachDB, MongoDB (if accessing >2 GB), the Dolphin emulator, and OpenMW. However, likewise you'll lose out on other features or programs that may be less-supported with a 64-bit kernel (e.g. gaming with brcmEGL + dispmanx).

> `arm_control=0x200`
>
> Why is it not working?

It seems you've skipped the key step of actually copying in the 64-bit kernel and its modules. That eLinux article may also be out-of-date as the default Raspbian Stretch bootloader will [automatically boot kernel8.img if present](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/boot.md).

If you aren't [building a 64-bit kernel from source](https://devsidestory.com/build-a-64-bit-kernel-for-your-raspberry-pi-3/), you can download a working version from the original author of this article, [here on GitHub](https://github.com/bamarni/pi64/releases) (Pi 3B only). His image is based on Debian arm64, and if you intend to use this kernel with Raspbian make sure to copy in `/boot/{kernel8.img,*.dtb,overlays,config.txt,cmdline.txt}` and `/lib/modules/` from the Pi64 image. You may also download and install such pre-configured Raspbian images:

- [Crazyhead90's Raspbian Stretch Lite and Desktop 64-bit images](https://github.com/Crazyhead90/pi64/releases) (Pi 3B+)
- [sakaki's Raspbian Buster Desktop 64-bit image](https://isshoni.org/downloads/raspbian_buster_64bit_kernel.img.xz) (Pi 4B)

Back to part of your other question:

> (taking into account I'm willing to compile some C++ programs in the future).

If it's your intent to use your Pi 3 to develop and test both armhf and arm64 applications, you might as well run Pi64 directly. Unlike Raspbian, it has support for MultiArch and thus doesn't require running 64-bit containers. Outside of the Raspbian/Debian ecosystem, other 64-bit distros include Ubuntu Server, Gentoo, openSUSE, and Fedora (see others' comments).

Comment: OpenGL doesn't provide hardware acceleration for 64-bit systems? Or is that only in the Pi?

Comment: @JAB my comment was specific to Pi 64-bit kernel status, although the problem is [rather unclear](https://github.com/bamarni/pi64/issues/37) at this time. Even on my system I can `modprobe vc4` and get 60+ fps glxgears, while Minecraft Java Edition is crawling. Also, gentoo-on-rpi3-64bit claims VC4 compatibility in its subject line. I've edited my post to remove mention of OpenGL until I have something more factual.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it even worth switching from ARMv7 to ARMv8?

Not unless you are running a kernel and OS userland compiled for ARMv8; there are at least a few such things for the Pi 3 around, including [Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM/Raspberry_Pi#Raspberry_Pi_3_aarch64_support).  For some hints about why there still isn't a special version of Raspbian, see here:

[Raspbian moving to 64-bit mode](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/43921/5538)

Otherwise, I think the only relevance is in what the processor reports itself as, which can be found via `/proc/cpuinfo`.  Some people use this as a means of telling one model of pi from another, although the practice is obviously not widespread.  Put another way, unless you know of a reason to do so, there isn't one.

Comment: So there is no other gain other that v8 is 64 bit (and can support 64b OS)?

Comment: Again, whatever benefit there is from running a 64-bit system would require software compiled to exploit it, starting with the kernel (since otherwise anything else will not work).  So as far as I am aware, enabling this won't make any difference (and from the sound of things may create a problem).

Comment: Fedora is hardly obscure and has offered aarch64 on the RPi3 almost from the day the RPi3 hit the market. [Download here.](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM/Raspberry_Pi#Raspberry_Pi_3_aarch64_support) @madneon

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Thanks for the update -- Fedora is in fact my preferred distro, I use [the stock arm7](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/27544/5538) on 2's & 3's.  It is a bit odd I missed that though (the wiki says pi support in general has been around since v. 25, which would be closer to a year after the 3 was released).  Anyway, edited.

Comment: Ah yes, right, there were 23 and 24 aarch64 builds but they were unofficial.

Answer (score 3):

As of today, it seems [Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM) and [Archlinux](https://archlinuxarm.org/about/downloads) are well supported.

If you go the Arch way, [this](https://github.com/peel/arm-sdcard-builder) will help you build the image (for me on linux / rpi3 it was `make linux`) and [this](https://ladvien.com/installing-arch-linux-raspberry-pi-zero-w/) will help you start wifi.

In case you need to be sure which raspberry you have, use [this guide](https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/blog/2016/11/21/how-to-identify-which-model-of-the-raspberry-pi-you-have).

Also `arm_control=0x200` is deprecated and `arm_64bit` should be used instead in `/boot/config.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it even worth switching from ARMv7 to ARMv8

I've just been looking into this. I benchmarked some programs and one saw a substantial performance increase. Digger deeper it turns out to be because ARMv8 adds a new instruction for integer division that is substantially faster than the traditional assembly routine.

So there's at least one reason to upgrade to v8!

Otherwise, I must confess, ARMv8 looks almost identical to ARMv7.

**EDIT**: I tell a lie. Turns out I am talking about AArch32 when the 64-bit mode has AArch64 which is a substantially different instruction set according to [this great presentation](https://armkeil.blob.core.windows.net/developer/Files/pdf/graphics-and-multimedia/ARM_CPU_Architecture.pdf).