# Is Mongodb latest version available on Raspberry PI 3 B?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, mongodb

I'm trying to install mongodb on Raspbian or Ubuntu Mate, but i have troubles finding de package on the repository to install it. The only one that is available is 2.4, but i'm having problems with this version because i need to import some data to a database to do some testing, but i'm getting this error:

"exception: BSON representation of supplied JSON array is too large: code FailedToParse: Date expecting integer milliseconds: offset:909"

I'm using this structure for the data that i'm importing:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5daa12bc95f4f6288c93727b"},"names":["frecuency","VLine1","VLine2","VLine3","ILine1","ILine2","ILine3","ITotal","PTotal","QTotal","STotal","TotalPower","actImpEnergy","actExpEnergy","indEnergy","capEnergy","apEnergy"],"values":[{"$numberDouble":"59.9462890625"},{"$numberDouble":"128.0234375"},{"$numberDouble":"127.263671875"},{"$numberDouble":"128.37890625"},{"$numberDouble":"272.2890625"},{"$numberInt":"280"},{"$numberDouble":"261.0390625"},{"$numberDouble":"813.328125"},{"$numberInt":"68934"},{"$numberInt":"-76578"},{"$numberInt":"104006"},{"$numberDouble":"-0.709518432617"},{"$numberInt":"114735486"},{"$numberInt":"14946131"},{"$numberInt":"1181895"},{"$numberInt":"128541205"},{"$numberInt":"192981465"}],"units":["Hz","V","V","V","A","A","A","A","W","VAr","VA","cos(phi)","Wh","Wh","VArh-ind","VArh-cap","VAh"],"codDispo":{"$numberInt":"1"},"time":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1571409000305"}}}
```

And this is how i'm importing the data:

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName.json --jsonArray
```

I've searched the error and it seems to be fixed when you upgrade mongodb version at least to 2.6.

But the issue is that i need at least 3.4 version because i'm using it on windows and i need to use it on Raspberry for the company needs.

Hope you know something. Thank you.

Comment: What is the Raspbian version?

Comment: @M.Rostami Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Comment: It's a 32bit OS, so, the MongoDB has been updated for 64bit OSs. Therefore, you can't use it on Raspbian. Maybe you could run a 64bit OS like Fedora or Arch to achieve this goal. Check [this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77693/enabling-armv8-on-raspberry-pi-3-b) out.

Comment: @M.Rostami So, the only way i can use Mongodb latest version is running it on 64bit OS? Which one do you recommend? I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. Meanwhile i'm going to try using Fedora.

Comment: You can install Debian (not Raspbian), Arch Linux, Ubuntu ARM64, Fedora, openSUSE, etc. Also, I just updated the answer.

Comment: @DavidRamírez that is correct. I have successfully used 64-bit Debian on a Pi 4 to run the latest release (6.3) of MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly install `mongodb_3.4.18-2+b1` (ARM64) on Raspbian over [debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mongodb), so, follow the procedure:

**1.** Download the package:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mongodb/mongodb_3.4.18-2+b1_arm64.deb
```

**2.** Install the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i mongodb_3.4.18-2+b1_arm64.deb
```

Finished.

---

In addition, you may face a problem because of the architecture of this package which is `ARMv8`. So, try [this procedure - *Enabling ARMv8 on Raspberry Pi 3 B*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77693/enabling-armv8-on-raspberry-pi-3-b).

---

**UPDATE:**
As the comments on the question, you need a 64bit os to install newer MongoDB on the Raspberry Pi, because they've stopped updating the package on a 32bit operating system like Raspbian.

As you said that you're free to install a new OS on your Raspberry Pi, you can install [Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM/Raspberry_Pi#aarch64_supported_images_for_Raspberry_Pi_3), [Arch Linux](https://gist.github.com/gea0/4fc2be0cb7a74d0e7cc4322aed710d38), [Ubuntu Server](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi), etc.

Also, there is another method that you can make the Raspbian 32bit(`armhf`) to 64bit(`arm64`). The keyword is "**Multiarch**". It lets you install library packages from multiple architectures on the same machine. I didn't implement Multiarch yet, however, check these links out:
[Multiarch - HOWTO](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)
[Multiarch - Implementation](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Implementation)

Comment: enabling ARMv8 *kernel* won't enable 64 bit in *userland* - Raspbian does not include any 64bit libraries, so this won't work

Comment: @M. Rostami If i try the Raspbian Multiarch method can i install mongodb as i should do with Debian? Or should i try with Fedora directly instead?

Comment: @DavidRamírez It is said that you can. I mean, as the description of Multiarch, you are able to install it. However, I didn't test.

Comment: @M.Rostami To confirm the info: Can i try Multiarch on Raspbian or i should try it on Debian instead?

Comment: @DavidRamírez Yes, you can. Feel free to try it on a system you don't care about and report what happens.